# Как завершить выполнение интервала?

Tags: javascript

```js
function d(){
 console.log('hello');
}

setInterval(function(){
  d()
  clearInterval(d, 5000);
}, 1000)
```

Comment: "Если бы я хоть разок прочел про глаз!" - http://smartfiction.ru/prose/waiting_interest/

Comment: @Igor Здравствуйте я что-то не догнал ...

Comment: @Igor я прочел Вы будете профессором а я буду к вам приходить :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function d(){
 console.log('hello');
}

t=setInterval(function(){
  d();
  clearInterval(t);
}, 1000)
```

Comment: как сделать чтобы интервал завершится через 5 секунд ?

Comment: `setTimeout(() => clearInterval(t), 5000);`

Comment: @Igor а как называется => ? можете объяснить или дать ссылку где почитать ?

Comment: Это называется "стрелочные функции". Традиционный вариант: `setTimeout(function() { clearInterval(t); }, 5000);`

Comment: @Leks https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @Igor ясно спасибо сейчас почитаю

Comment: @Leks как я понял он только заменяет слово function верно ?

Comment: @Leks в общем и целом да. Но ещё `this` стрелочной функции на самом деле не стрелочной функции, а того контекста, который эту функцию вызвал.

Comment: @Alex Sazonov ок спасибо потом еще раз почитаю